# I am receiving this SyntaxError in Python

Tags: python

```
coin = 'BTC'
start_str = 'August 15, 2021'

klines = client.get_historical_klines(symbol = f'{coin}USDT', interval = client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1MINUTE, start_str)

Input In [2]
    klines = client.get_historical_klines(symbol = f'{coin}USDT', interval = client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1MINUTE, start_str)
                                                                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

Comment: The error message is quite clear. You should explain what you are trying to do and why you think you should be putting a positional argument at the end of your function arguments

Comment: Do you know what positional arguments and keyword arguments are?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the error message `SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument`, the problem is you called a function and passed a positional argument after the keyword ones.

In Python, keyword arguments (the ones you pass with `name=value`) should always be after positional ones.

Positional and keyword arguments are explained [in the official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-argument).

Answer (score 0):

```
coin = 'BTC'
start_str = 'August 15, 2021'
klines = client.get_historical_klines(coin, Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1MINUTE, start_str)
#klines = client.get_historical_klines(symbol = f'{coin}USDT', interval = client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1MINUTE, start_str)
```

Is this what you want?
It is in the documentation of Binance

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
start_str = "june 15, 2022"
klines = client.get_historical_klines(symbol = f'{coin}USDT', interval=client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1MINUTE, start_str=start_str)

Documentation of the Binance follows above. Test, Copie, and paste.
```

Comment: You may want to add an explanation of your answer, code only answer much like code only questions tend to be poorly received.

Comment: Please include an explanation with your answer to help readers understand how this works, and solves the problem. You can click the edit button at the bottom of your answer to add an explanation. Additionally, you may find it beneficial reading [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)